Reduce QrCode generation time in python
I've been tasked with writing a Python script that generates a specified number of QR codes and saves each one on a separate page in a PDF file. Each QR code is placed on a template that includes the company logo at the top and bottom. While my current code works, generating 10,000 QR codes takes around 200 seconds. I've been asked to optimize this process to reduce the time to under 40 seconds. How can I achieve better multithreading to meet this requirement?
The code is given below
import os
import qrcode
import time
import tempfile
from PIL import Image
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

def generate_qr_code(data, height_inches, width_inches, dpi=320):
    height = height_inches * dpi
    width = width_inches * dpi

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=15,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    img = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)

    return img

def add_qr_to_template(template_path, qr_img, qr_position):
    template_path = os.path.expanduser(template_path)
    
    try:
        template = Image.open(template_path)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error opening template image: {e}")
        return None

    template.paste(qr_img, qr_position)
    return template 


def add_qr_to_pdf(pdf_canvas, qr_img, qr_position):
    # Save the QR code image to a temporary file
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.png') as temp_file:
        qr_img.save(temp_file, format='PNG')
        temp_file_path = temp_file.name 

     # Draw the image from the temporary file
    pdf_canvas.drawImage(temp_file_path, 0, 0, width=289.2, height=418.50)
    pdf_canvas.showPage()

    # Clean up the temporary file
    os.remove(temp_file_path) 

def generate_and_add_qr_to_pdf(pdf_canvas, data, qr_position, template_path):
    qr_img = generate_qr_code(data, 2, 2)
    template = add_qr_to_template(template_path, qr_img, qr_position)
    if template:
        add_qr_to_pdf(pdf_canvas, template, qr_position)


def main():
    num_qr_codes = int(input("Enter the number of QR codes to generate: "))
    data = "examplesite.com"
    template_path = "QrGenerator/company_logo.png"

    qr_position = (2, 252)  # Adjust this to fit your PDF

    pdf_path = "QrGenerator/qr_codes.pdf"
    custom_size=(289.29,418.50)
    c = canvas.Canvas(pdf_path, pagesize=custom_size)
    
    start_time = time.time()

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:

        futures = []
        for i in range(num_qr_codes):
            futures.append(executor.submit(generate_and_add_qr_to_pdf, c, data, qr_position, template_path))
    
        # Wait for all threads to complete
        for future in as_completed(futures):
            future.result()
    
    # Save the PDF
    c.save()

    end_time = time.time()
    total_time = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Time taken to generate and save {num_qr_codes} QR codes into PDF: {total_time:.2f} seconds")
    print(f"PDF saved as {pdf_path}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() 


QrCode images are ideal to generate with 1x1 blocks, and the resizing to the correct block size might then even been done in the PDF, maybe at the client. There do no ANTIALIAS. Check into Black&White. That should probably be faster than improving for concurrency. Is PDF needed?

yes pdf is needed,and may i know what you mean by Black&White? @Joop

I am unfamiliar with Python's image processing, but with image formats you might pick a bit image. First I would try wether smaller images are faster and whether they are usable here.

@JoopEggen Thanks for the bit image suggestion,i was able to chop off 50 seconds ,now 10,000 qr codes gets generated in about 150 seconds rather than 200,i still want to reduce the time much more ,perhaps less than 80 seconds anything else i can try?

I would be interested what effect has commenting out "resize". Does that cost time. Other ideas, besides the obvious "Python is slow" I have not.

A couple of suggestions:
First, creating and resizing a bitmap (QR code) is CPU-intensive, for which multiprocessing is better suited than multithreading. Second, I don't believe you will gain much by concurrently writing to disk your PNG files. Depending on your hardware, this could even hurt performance.
If your actual data for each image is dynamically generated, then you can save some time and memory by using a generator function or generator expression for generating the data. I would then use the multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap function specifying a suitable chunksize argument based on the pool size and the number of images being created. Using the concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor.submit or the more-or-less equivalent multiprocessing.pool.Pool.apply_async method does not allow for tasks to be chunked resulting in many more writing and reading operations to the pool's internal queues. Chunking provides larger but fewer read/write queue operations and is highly recommended when the number of tasks being submitted is "large." The imap method being used will return the results from submitted tasks in task-submission order as soon as a result is returned from the worker function.
Note that in your current code the order in which submitted tasks complete is not defined. This does not matter since you are generating identical PNG files for each PDF page. But if in your "real code" you need a specific PNG file for each page, your code will not work since the second task submitted to the pool might complete first and you will end up adding the PNG image meant for the second page to the first page instead. If the order that the PNG files are added truly does not matter, then in the following code replace the call to method imap with imap_unordered for better performance.
Here is the general idea of how you would use multiprocessing to produce the PNG images but serially add them to the PDF file:
import qrcode
from PIL import Image
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
from functools import partial

def generate_qr_code(data, height_inches, width_inches, dpi=320):
    height = height_inches * dpi
    width = width_inches * dpi

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=15,
        border=4,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    img = img.resize((width, height))

    return img


def main():
    N_QR_CODES = 1_000  # Just for demo purposes
    DATA = 'https://examplesite.com'

    def generate_data():
        """For demo purposes generate identical data."""

        for _ in range(N_QR_CODES):
            yield DATA

    def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
        chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
        if remainder:
            chunksize += 1
        return chunksize

    t = time.time()

    pool_size = cpu_count()
    iterable_size = N_QR_CODES
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size)

    worker = partial(generate_qr_code, height_inches=2, width_inches=2)
    with Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        # Use a generator or generator function if you are able to:
        for img in pool.imap(worker, generate_data(), chunksize=chunksize):
            # Write out image or add to PDF
            ...
        print(time.time() - t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Note
If you comment out the call to img.resize, then the type of img is qrcode.image.pil.PilImage, which cannot be pickled (required for using multiprocessing with either concurrent.futures or multiprocessing.pool.Pool). After calling resize, the new type of img is qrcode.image.pil.PilImage, which can be pickled. Thus, in this code resizing is required.

will the time taken be reduced further if i run this in aws lambda

I really can't answer that.
